# any way to integrate authentication with subsystem for linux?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Looking at windows docs and trying to script this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-debian-gnulinux -OutFile distro.zip -UseBasicParsing
Expand-Archive distro.zip debian
cd distro
.\debian.exe (edited)
```

After I run debian.exe I have to create a new user and password.

Is there any way to use the windows user and password? Or any tool that can do this? I want to have users seamlessly use wsl with their windows accounts.

Comment: Are the tags correct?  I didn’t think 2016 supported wsl.  Did you mean 2019?

Comment: 1803 supports wsl

Comment: Ok, but 1803, isn't 2016.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native AD integration in WSL as the App that uses WSL lives in the %APPDATA% folder of each user's profile, so it is something they setup on their first run without much of a way to configure it ahead of the first run.